# How to end socket with 408 Request Timeout in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sockets, http, server

I am capturing a timeout event on my http server with the following code and I want to return the error code 408 but its not working. It works fine when I return "400 Bad Request" instead.

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
   // other code
}).listen(5000)
server.on('timeout', (socket) => {
   socket.end(['HTTP/1.0 408 Request Timeout\r\n'])
})
```

The above gives me a client side error: Server returned nothing (no headers, no data)

Comment: The line terminator in HTTP is specified as `\r\n`, not `\n.

Comment: I tried \r\n but it still gives me the following result:
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Connection: close

Comment: You need two of them, one to terminate the header and one to terminate the headsrs.

Comment: Previously it was two \r\n\r\n pairs which I removed cause it wasn't making much difference :)